# WAMP - php artisan command becomes slow in WAMP 3.0

Tags: php, laravel, wamp

I used WAMP 3.0 for my local environment (Windows 7). I didn't change anything on the environment, and the "php artisan" command suddenly became very slow. The command would not return with a display within minutes.

I switched back and forth on PHP, 5.6.16 and 7.0.0, both supported in WAMP 3.0. And they are all the same. How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have xdebug enabled in wamp 3? Composer is much slower with xdebug enabled, maybe artisan has the same issue

Comment: No, I didn't have xdebug enabled. There are 3 settings related to xdebug, as I see in PHP settings, and none of them is enabled.

Comment: so it was fast then youve made code changes and its slow? or has it always been slow in wamp 3?

Comment: In wamp 3, always slow. I just upgarded my wamp 2 to wamp 3, and it became slow. Nothing else was changed. Not an issue in wamp 2 though.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of reasons why WAMP could be running slow. Please refer to this page on some things to try to correct that:

https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/wamp-is-running-very-slow

For me, what helped was disabling cgi_module in Apache. This can be done by:

Click the green "W" -> Apache -> Apache Modules -> Uncheck: cgi_module.